Is it possible to use CDI before Quarkus.run is called?
I want to write a simple CLI application with two commands: start and stop.
'start' is to start the Quarkus HTTP server and 'stop' is to stop it.
I use Picocli to parse the command line.
With a custom @QuarkusMain class it is possible to use Picocli to parse the command line arguments and to start Quarkus only if the given command is 'start'.
Now I want to inject some CDI beans, but it seams CDI isn't ready before Quarkus.run is called.
Is there a way I can achieve this?
This is what I tried:
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import picocli.CommandLine;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;

@QuarkusMain
public class MyApp {

    public static final Path PID_FILE = Path.of( "myapp.pid" );

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.exit( new CommandLine( new MainCommand() ).execute( args ) );
    }

    @Command(
        name = "myapp"
    ,   version = "1.0"
    ,   mixinStandardHelpOptions = true
    ,   subcommands = {
            StartCommand.class
        ,   StopCommand.class
        }
    )
    static class MainCommand implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // show usage, if there are no arguments
            CommandLine.usage( this, System.out );
        }
    }

    @Command( name = "start", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true )
    static class StartCommand implements Runnable {

        @Inject
        GreetingService greetingService;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // get PID of current process
                long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
                // and write it to a file
                Files.write( PID_FILE, String.valueOf( pid ).getBytes() );
                // now run the Quarkus server
                
                // !!! access to greetingService leads to NPE
                System.out.println( greetingService.greetings() );

                Quarkus.run();
            }
            catch ( IOException ex ) {
                throw new IllegalStateException( ex );
            }
        }

    }

    @Command( name = "stop", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true )
    static class StopCommand implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if ( Files.exists( PID_FILE ) ) {
                try {
                    String pidString = new String( Files.readAllBytes( PID_FILE ) );
                    long   pid       = Long.parseLong( pidString );

                    // Send SIGTERMto process
                    ProcessHandle.of( pid ).ifPresent( ProcessHandle::destroy );

                    // delete PID file
                    Files.delete( PID_FILE );
                }
                catch ( IOException ex ) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException( ex );
                }
            }
            else {
                System.err.println( "No instance of myapp running." );
                System.exit( 1 );
            }
        }

    }

    @Dependent
    static class GreetingService {

        public String greetings() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
    
}


Any help is appreciated.

Looking at the code, I suspect that it isn't possible. Normally, if we create instances by calling new ...., we are on our own (i.e. the CDI container does not know anything about them). If the CDI container is already initialized, I think we could retrieve the already constructed bean-instance (or at least a proxy) from the container. This, however, requires that the CDI container is bootstrapped already, which I heavily suspect that it isn't since we are in the main method and nothing has been initialized yet.

@Turing85 is exactly right. Quarkus is a container that contains your application -- not a library you can control from the outside.

You can kind of do this, but you have to be aware that you're swimming against the current, and will have to take some care to the order in which you do things.
Stripping to basics:

You can use @QuarkusMain, but also implement QuarkusApplication.
Define public int run(String... args) throws Exception { .. } this is effectively a bean that is used instead of the static main. You can use injected resources within (and for things launched from) this method.
In that run method, define a Picocli CommandLine yourself. You specifically want to use an explicit ExecutionStrategy to run your command. This can be as simple as another method call.

public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
    CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine(...);
    return cmd.setExecutionStrategy(this::executionStrategy).execute(args);
}
private int executionStrategy(ParseResult parseResult) {
    // DO THINGS based on parsed arguments
    return 0; // return an exit code
}

For my own (toy) application, I was using Quarkus Camel. I used CamelMain to avoid starting anything unless the command was run with no arguments. It isn't exactly what you're trying to do, but it is close.
The important part was using a custom execution strategy to launch things from the QuarkusApplication/injected run method. You then have more control over what is happening and can make decisions based on arguments and parameters.
HTH

Thank you @ebullient. I tried that, but that does not solve the problem as a whole. Now I can start Quarkus with the start command, but when I run the stop command - or even without any command - Quarkus complains about another running process :-/

If you open a discussion in the Quarkus GH Repo, we can walk through your whole scenario to find a way to do what you need. With this little tidbit, you may need to borrow a bit from what we did for some of the quarkus commands, but what would help first is a better overview of your intended command/invocation pattern.

Currently I work around it by disabling the http listener (quarkus.http.host-enabled) and enabling it in a custom main method where I parse the args myself:
    public static void main( String[] args ) {         if ( args.length > 0 && "start".equals( args[0] ) ) {             System.setProperty( "quarkus.http.host-enabled", "true" );         }         Quarkus.run( Main.class, args );     }

Yep, that is one way to do it.
